# Print multiple documents in a folder

Tags: c++, printing, com, atl, printer-properties

I just need to print multiple documents inside a folder using C++ code. I am using `IOleCommandTarget.Exec()` method.

For the first time I have to show the print configuration dialog( I have set 
"`OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER`" to show the print config dialog for the first print) and get the user inputs like paper orientation, number of copies etc. Same setting I have to use for subsequent documents.

Can anybody say how to get user inputs that set for first print? Also I have seen the next print is not waiting for 'user input' in print dialog(which is showing for first doc print). How to make it synchronous?

Here is my code:

```
 CComQIPtr<IOleCommandTarget> spCommandTarget(DocumentObj); 
 spCommandTarget->Exec(&CGID_MSHTML, IDM_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Maybe if you add a bit of code and show us where you have the problem on your code someone will help you.

Comment: I am adding code snippet here.

`
CComQIPtr<IOleCommandTarget> spCommandTarget(DocumentObj);
spCommandTarget->Exec(&CGID_MSHTML, IDM_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT, NULL, NULL);`